# Color by in Combination Chart

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

Consider the following chart:
[image]

We have data for 2016 and 2017, and we'd like to show green bars for 2016 and red bars for 2017. In a normal bar chart, this can be accomplished with a color by Year. However, there is no "color by" option for a combination chart.

I found a response [here](https://community.tibco.com/questions/color-combination-chart), but it was for stacking different color bars.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue atm, have you found a workaround by the time?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no solution other than a JSViz. There is probably a Tibco Idea that can be voted up though.